# Display input by clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html

For example when i give an input saying "Good Morning" in the submit button. I should be able to view my input on the Html web page.

```
<input id="a"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="e()">Submit<button
<p id="k"></p>
```

Comment: A submit button can't contain interactive elements, you can't input to/in a submit button. Please be more specific, what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: please show what have you tyried so far

Comment: Okay. So i have a submit button and i insert a value i should be able to read my input on the web page. just as a regular  text nothing else.. is it Possible??

Comment: @AllenSamuel Submit button is purposed to submit a form to a server. then the server can return a page containing the value of the input in the text of that page. If you don't need form submission, don't use submit button, use a regular button instead, or listen input or change event of the input element and in the handler add the value to the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do, but assuming I undertood correctly. You want to take an **input's value** & output it in the **[DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)** when submitting the form.

You can check a code working sample **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/npuxqt3s/)**. Notice kindly that you can reuse this function again in another input by changing the **parameters**.

```js
const submitForm = (value, displayer) => {
 let input = document.getElementById(value);
 let valueHolder = document.getElementById(displayer);
 let inputValue = input.value;

 valueHolder.innerHTML = inputValue;
    input.value = '';
};

const form = document.getElementById('formSubmission');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 submitForm('inputData', 'valueHolder');
});
```

```html
<form id="formSubmission">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something..." id="inputData" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<h1 id="valueHolder"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a function on click of submit and fetch the value of the input box. Using `.innerHTML` append the value to the paragraph or a div

```js
function e()
{
document.querySelector('#k').innerHTML=document.querySelector('#a').value
}
```

```html
<input id="a"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="e()" value="Submit">
<p id="k"></p>
```

Comment: Now it's not a submit button.

Comment: As soon as this is put into a form, the form will be submitted